# Reserve a product before purchase

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I am trying to work out whether it is possible to reserve a product with the option to then either purchase or cancel at a later date.

I appreciate this goes against the idea of "selling" but i am setting up a site for selling limited edition pieces of art. Sometimes the pieces will be reserved by an agent before a sale is agreed.

Also, as most of the pieces will be paid by bank transfer, technically the piece of art is not sold until the money has been transferred and funds cleared.

Any thoughts or ideas on this would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just sell them, create a payment method named "Reserved" then you can edit later the order in the backend, change the payment method and you are fine.

So no changes on magento are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a psuedo-purchase such that the product is unsellable when a reservation is made.  You can create an observer or something that will watch for these events and it will change the status of the item upon event.

Good luck!